# Android 2.2 google library for admob crash the app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, google-play-services

I've launched an app few weeks ago, My app is for every android version. I'm using admob services via new google play library as recently changed by google.
but  my app crashed on Android 2.2, device : Optimus One (thunderc). I've surfed through the web for this error but can't find any solution. Here what crash report says

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.IOException.<init>
at com.google.android.gms.internal.k.f(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.k.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.i.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.i.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.cs.aY(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.do$1.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.dp$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what version of google play services are you using?

Comment: version name : 4.4.52-000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2.2` does not and will not have that version of google play services. That version is only compatible with `2.3` and up. if you need to support 2.2 you need to download `google play services for froyo` in the sdk manager and only use that version. so my suggestion is for you to drop 2.2 support or you are forever stuck on that version of google play services